# Adding Shadow To Customized TabBar

Tags: swift

I have a tab bar that I'm trying to customize it's look. So far, I changed it's background color and added corner radius. I'm trying to add a shadow to it, but I can't get it to work.
I tried few solutions, but nothing worked for me. There is not errors or anything, but it just won't work. This is what I have so far:

```
private func setupTabBarAppearance() {
    let CORNER_RADIUS: CGFloat = 20

    let tabBar = self.tabBar
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.appWhite
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .lightGray
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.appBlue
    tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
    tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS
    tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    tabBar.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: tabBar.frame.height), byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: CORNER_RADIUS, height: CORNER_RADIUS)).cgPath
    shapeLayer.path = path
    shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 5)
    shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 10
    shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = true
    shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    tabBar.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    tabBar.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

I have two problems with this that I don't find a solution to, which is:

1. I can't get the shapeLayer to be behind tabBar, it just covers it.
2. The shadow from shapeLayer is facing downwards so even if I would be able to get the shapeLayer to be behind the tab bar, the shadow still won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s just tackle this part:

```
tabBar.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Obviously if you add a shape layer to the tab bar’s own layer, the shape layer must be in front. That is what it means to be a sublayer.

If you want to cast a shadow using a custom shape, you will need a completely separate view hidden behind your tab bar.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I tried to create a UIView with shadow and place it behind the tab bar with no luck. this method is from a subclass of UITabBarController, can it be what causes the problem with adding the UIView?

Comment: You didn’t show that code so I have no idea. I answered about the code in your actual question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Anyhow, I'm trying a different approach as I see that the tabbar is not very customizable.

Comment: Correct, I didn't want to say anything but in my view the entire enterprise is somewhat dubious. Note though that at least if you make a tab bar controller in a storyboard you can substitute a tab bar subclass. So you might be able to get some mileage out of that.

Comment: Thank you Matt! And again, I really appreciate that you took the time to answer, and I'm sorry if I wasted your time :).

Comment: Not at all, I wasn’t much help I know.